# MYSQL search through cells with comma separated values

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an AJAX call which passes an array of variables (ids) through to a function which will then query a database to return rows if this ids exist in their 'catid' cell.

I know how to use an array to use an 'IN' MYSQL command but in this instance there are multiple ids stored in a cell for rows, seperated by a comma. This is stored as a varchar.
Is there any way I can loop through the individual ids stored in a rows categories cell?

Here is a screenshot of an example row from the database. I have highlighted the 'catid' cell for rows. As you can see, a row can be part of many categories, with these category id's seperated by a comma)...

[image]

Comment: So that field is storing a literal string? As in `18,26,32` is a string in your database that you're trying to query.

Comment: That's correct. I wouldn't have designed the database that way but it's not my database!

Comment: What about using [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sign of bad DB design you should first look into [**Database Normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and if you can change the structure then first normalize it by using a junction table ,As of now you can use [*FIND_IN_SET()*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to find your corresponding record id in your comma separated ids column

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('id1',column) > 0
AND FIND_IN_SET('id2',column) > 0
AND FIND_IN_SET('id3',column) > 0
```

Change the operator as per your wish i have shown example with AND operator,note you need to use `FIND_IN_SET` as many times as the no of ids you have in your array that you need to compare with your column

Comment: I know this but I didn't design the database and can't change it. I would not design it this way. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @devoncrazylegs then you need to use the above approach but sometimes it sucks performance